# Ubuntu 18.04 program not starting and not shown in software center

Tags: 18.04, software-center, skype, desktop-apps

Today after I reached my desk, suddenly apps shortcut in dock didn't work for few programs like 'skype', 'atom', 'system monitor' etc. They were fine earlier. I checked 'Software center' and there weren't those program. I tried 'recovery mode' as well but they didn't appear. I had to reinstall all non working apps/program from their respective site, checking ubuntu supported version. Please check this issue, team.

Comment: hey @Raw did you ever find a solution to this? I think I might be experiencing a similar problem with all electron built apps.